# Can we use LinqToExcel on Shared Hosting Env like GoDaddy

Tags: shared-hosting, linq-to-excel

I am planning to use LinqToExcel for reading of my excels files but i am not sure whether it will work on Shared Hosting env like GoDaddy?

Answer (score 2):

It probably won't work because the [Ace database engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) will have to be installed on the server so LinqToExcel can read the excel files. And I don't think most shared hosting providers will allow you to install it.

You can try though, and let me know if it does work.

Comment: :) ,  nice answer , that i also know , is there any way to do this?